# Screen warping on Nexus 4 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

When running my app on a Nexus 4 running 5.0.1 I'm seeing this occur. What could be causing this? I've never seen this before. It appears to me that the face drawing on the screen is persisting... possibly being caused by just the face being invalidated rather than the entire screen? Below is the code I use to animate the face, my guess is this is occurring due to when I start the animation and how I'm invalidating the view.

This does not occur on an emulator running 5.0.1.

The View being invalidated is just the face.

```
private Handler frame = new Handler();
private Runnable frameUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    synchronized public void run() {
        frame.removeCallbacks(frameUpdate);
        ((Face) findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).invalidate();
        frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final View root = findViewById(R.id.root);
    root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            // Graphics
            initGfx();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            else
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}

synchronized public void initGfx() {
    frame.removeCallbacks(frameUpdate);
    frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: please give us more information... Some code would also be useful. Have you tried running it on the Emulator running an emulated Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1? Do you get the same result? Have you tried this on a phone running Android 4.4.4 and below to see if you get the same result?

Comment: updated, I have never seen this elsewhere, I've tried it on real devices and emulators running KitKat and received this as feedback from someone using a Lollipop Nexus 4. I have a feeling it is the manner in which I'm invalidating the Face.